# Upgrading APK version of Monerujo with Google Play Beta version

Tags: mnemonic-seed, android-wallet, monerujo

When I install the new updated [v8 Silver Colobus](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/releases/tag/v0.8) Monerujo Beta version from the [Google Play store](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.m2049r.xmrwallet) can I use my existing password and wallet files created by [v7 Gray Grilse](https://github.com/m2049r/xmrwallet/releases/tag/v0.7) or will I need to recover with my mnemonic seed?

Answer (score 2):

it should work. BUT it may not, because the wallet folder has been renamed from "Monerujo" to "monerujo" (small m) so you may need to rename the folder with a file explorer.